# String Join but not fully

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

Suppose I have the following string list:

```
l={{"a","dog"},{"the","pen"}}
```

how can I turn this to

```
{{"a dog"},{"the pen"}}
```

I tried `StringJoin` yet that gives

```
{{"adog"},{"thepen"}}
```

Comment: Look at [`StringRiffle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringRiffle.html).

Comment: @JasonB. I have but that does not a list format.

Comment: even if I do `{l // StringRiffle}` I get `{"a dog\nthe pen"}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List /@ StringRiffle /@ l
```

> {{"a dog"}, {"the pen"}}